# Return the number of records where condition met within time intervals in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I am at the beginning of learning SQL, and this problem gives me a headache. I have a table where I want to work with these columns:

| updated_date | upload_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-03 09:10:50 | 2023-04-03 09:08:24 |
| 2023-04-03 09:14:55 | 2023-04-03 09:08:34 |
| 2023-04-03 09:23:51 | 2023-04-03 09:08:36 |
| 2023-04-03 09:25:53 | 2023-04-03 09:14:35 |
| 2023-04-03 09:28:43 | 2023-04-03 09:17:29 |
| 2023-04-03 10:29:06 | 2023-04-03 09:39:16 |
| 2023-04-03 10:53:15 | 2023-04-03 09:44:16 |
| 2023-04-03 10:24:40 | 2023-04-03 09:48:39 |

What I would need is the COUNT of records within 1 hour timeframe (let's say from 2023-04-03 09:00:00 to 2023-04-03 10:00:00) from the "upload_date" column, but only those where the processing time (updated_date - upload_date) takes more than 1 hour, plus return the average processing time (in hh:mm:ss format) in that group. This should be one row, the next row should contain the COUNTs between 10:00-11:00 and so on.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_of_feeds,
       AVG(TIMEDIFF(updated_date, upload_date)) AS average_processing_time
FROM   auk_feed_queue  
WHERE  TIMEDIFF(updated_date, upload_date) > '00:59:59'
```

But it returns all records from the table in one row, without the correct time format:

| number_of_feeds | average_processing_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1264 | 90274.3861 |

I would need multiple rows, each row contains 1 hour timeframe. How do I achieve that?

Comment: The trick is to generate a table that has every datetime, by the hour, that you want to care about. Generating it is something that I don't know how to do in mySQL.  Every RDBMS has a different way you might do that.  If you search specifically for "Generate series of datetimes in mysql" you might get that answered.  Once you have that, then you should be on your way by doing an inequality join from that table of unique datetimes, to this one

Comment: Could you give an example of your expected output, please?

Comment: Needs to be grouped by the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample data only has one result that has a duration greater than 1 hour. I added a second one.

```
CREATE TABLE data (updated_date DATETIME, upload_date DATETIME);
INSERT INTO data VALUES
('2023-04-03 09:10:50', '2023-04-03 09:08:24'),
('2023-04-03 09:14:55', '2023-04-03 09:08:34'),
('2023-04-03 09:23:51', '2023-04-03 09:08:36'),
('2023-04-03 09:25:53', '2023-04-03 09:14:35'),
('2023-04-03 09:28:43', '2023-04-03 09:17:29'),
('2023-04-03 10:29:06', '2023-04-03 09:39:16'),
('2023-04-03 10:53:15', '2023-04-03 09:44:16'),
('2023-04-03 11:53:15', '2023-04-03 10:27:16'), /*Added this row to create second result*/
('2023-04-03 10:24:40', '2023-04-03 09:48:39');
```

The query first gets the beginning of the hour of the upload date so we can group the results. Then count, get average, and set your 1 hour condition in the where.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(upload_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') upload_date_hr
     , COUNT(*) countOfDates
     , CAST(AVG(TIMEDIFF(updated_date, upload_date)) AS TIME) avgDuration
  FROM data d
 WHERE TIMEDIFF(updated_date, upload_date) >= '01:00:00'
 GROUP BY upload_date_hr
```

This returns:

| upload_date_hr | countOfDates | avgDuration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-03 09:00:00 | 1 | 01:08:59 |
| 2023-04-03 10:00:00 | 1 | 01:25:59 |

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/3FwrSa6U)

Answer (score 0):

You can find all hourly intervals in subquery, and then join the original table back onto it:

```
select t.d1 hour_interval, 
     sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(timediff(u.updated_date, u.upload_date)))) avg_duration, 
     count(*) cnt 
from (select distinct date_format(u.upload_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00.000') d1 from uploads u) t 
join uploads u on t.d1 <= u.upload_date and u.upload_date <= t.d1 + interval 1 day
where time_to_sec(timediff(u.updated_date, u.upload_date)) / 3600 > 1
group by t.d1
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Dbo6Bpjy)